# How to pass string at the end of scope

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically alter what I access from a Json file using string at the end of my $scope call.

```
 app.controller('dashboardCtrl', 
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'UserService',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $location, UserService) {

      var username = $rootScope.username;

      UserService.getUsers().success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data
        $scope.loggedInUser = $scope.users.username
      })
```

So I am trying to pass the var username at the end of the last line, instead of $scope.users.*username*. At the moment it just searches for a JSON object "username" instead of the actual string held in username.

This would mean I can search my JSON file for the logged in user depending on the rootScope variable that is username.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use bracket notation to access object fields via variable. `$scope.loggedInUser = $scope.users[username]` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. No amount of googling turned up a result. Very helpful.

Comment: As a note, that is a javascript feature and is not specific to angular. And is there any chance you can accept the answer?

Comment: Great thanks. I tried when I commented but it said I couldn't accept within 8 minutes. You were too quick ;) I can't upvote you either, I don't have the rep. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the key that is stored in `username` variable just do:

```
$scope.loggedInUser = $scope.users[username];
```